# How do I calculate AUC from two continuous variables in R?

Tags: r, roc, auc

I have the following data:

```
# actual value: 
a <- c(26.77814,29.34224,10.39203,29.66659,20.79306,20.73860,22.71488,29.93678,10.14384,32.63233,24.82544,38.14778,25.12343,23.07767,14.60789)

# predicted value
p <- c(27.238142,27.492240,13.542026,32.266587,20.473063,20.508603,21.414882,28.536775,18.313844,32.082333,24.545438,30.877776,25.703430,22.397666,15.627892)
```

I already calculated MSE and RMSE for these two, but they're asking for AUC and ROC curve. How can I calculate it from this data using R? I thought AUC is for classification problems, was I mistaken? Can we still calculate AUC for numeric values like above?

Comment: Who are "they"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question:

> I thought AUC is for classification problems, was I mistaken?

You are not mistaken. The area under the receiver operating characteristic curve can't be computed for two numeric vectors like in your example. It's used to determine how well your  binary classifier stands up to a gold standard binary classifier. You need a vector of cases vs. controls, or levels for the `a` vector that put each value in one of two categories.

Here's an example of how you'd do this with the `pROC` package:

```
library(pROC)

# actual value
a <- c(26.77814,29.34224,10.39203,29.66659,20.79306,20.73860,22.71488,29.93678,10.14384,32.63233,24.82544,38.14778,25.12343,23.07767,14.60789)

# predicted value
p <- c(27.238142,27.492240,13.542026,32.266587,20.473063,20.508603,21.414882,28.536775,18.313844,32.082333,24.545438,30.877776,25.703430,22.397666,15.627892)

df <- data.frame(a = a, p = p)

# order the data frame according to the actual values
odf <- df[order(df$a),]

# convert the actual values to an ordered binary classification 
odf$a <- odf$a > 12 # arbitrarily decided to use 12 as the threshold

# construct the roc object
roc_obj <- roc(odf$a, odf$p)
auc(roc_obj)
# Area under the curve: 0.9615
```

Here, we have arbitrarily decided that threshold for the gold standard (a) is 12. If that's the case, than observations that have a lower value than 12 are controls. The prediction (`p`) classifies very well, with an AUC of 0.9615. We don't have to decide on the threshold for our prediction classifier in order to determine the AUC, because it's independent of the threshold decision. We can slide up and down depending on whether it's more important to find cases or to not misclassify a control.

#### Important Note

I completely made up the threshold for the gold standard classifier. If you choose a different threshold (for the gold standard), you'll get a different AUC. For example, if we chose 28, the AUC would be 1. The AUC is independent of the threshold for the predictor, but absolutely depends on the threshold for the gold standard.

#### EDIT

To clarify the above note, which was apparently misunderstood, you were not mistaken. This kind of analysis is for classification problems. You cannot use it here without more information. In order to do it, you need a threshold for your `a` vector, which you don't have. You CAN'T make one up and expect to get a non made up result for the AUC. Because the AUC depends on the threshold for the gold standard classifier, if you just make up the threshold, as we did in the exercise above, you are also just making up the AUC.

Comment: Thresholding a continuous actual variable to perform ROC curve analysis in a non-binary classification setting sounds an awful lot like cheating to me. If it was stats.SE I'd downvote for even suggesting to do that (and as a reviewer reject your paper). But in terms of SO your answer is correct.

Comment: @Calimo in practice, as I expect you know, the actual variable is sometimes continuous. It just has a well established threshold. The point of this answer is that you can't do ROC curve analysis without a binary classification. Showing that two different thresholds give you different results for the area under the curve was done to demonstrate that.

Comment: I agree with @DanHall. I took it as a demonstration. I knew ROC is only done in classification problem, but when I was asked to calculate it, I was confused. The answer that Dan gave provided me a necessary knowledge backing to deny the request. We didn't have a clear threshold in our case.